# How can I hide MVC route?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

Can a special route address be created using the `app.MapControllerRoute` feature that comes standard in the ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Standard route configuration:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Route address output with standard configuration;

```
https://localhost:44331/Survey/ChooseOption?surveyId=1
```

Example of the route address you want to obtain;

```
https://localhost:44331/saHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7MgYIARBFGDsyBggCEEUYPDIGCAMQ
```

Comment: I want to make a point that this kind of system will be a extremely difficult to maintain and debug. I would strongly recommend against implementing something like this. Besides, this does not really do much in terms of "protecting your server" as users will still see exactly what URLs are being requested and the responses to these requests, and make sense of these obfuscated endpoints. Before you get into this, where have you seen a website ever using a mechanism like this? Can you give any examples of websites that have implemented a mechanism like this for "security"?

Comment: As a solution, I have seen solution suggestions on the internet such as "you can write a special view engine", but these suggestions are definitely very difficult solutions. I'm also wondering if I can find a solution to the "app.MapControllerRoute" method with bait configurations etc.

Comment: I honestly think you are wasting your time going after something like this. I would suggest instead looking for actual ways to secure a web server. For example, check out Manning's book "ASP.NET Core Security" (spoiler alert, it does not contain request path obfuscation). I actually wrote an answer explaining how it would be possible for the sake of answering a question, but I decided to delete it because I did not want anyone to actually do something so ridiculous (sorry, no offense. I just think it's pointless)